# guardar acciones realizadas en listview android

Tags: android, listview, baseadapter

Tengo un `listview` con un *base* *adapter*, cuyo llenado proviene de un *webservice*, ocupo la librería [LikeButton](https://github.com/jd-alexander/LikeButton) para animar el botón "me gusta"  misma que funciona correctamente, en si el problema es que al recorrer el `listview` para ver las opciones, y despues regresar, el *like* se desmarca y viceversa, dejo mi código:

```
public class ImagenAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable{
    Context ctx;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    ArrayList<FilterData>Datos;
    CustomFilter filtro;
    ArrayList<FilterData>filtroList;

    public ImagenAdapter(Context applicationContext, ArrayList<FilterData>Datos){
        this.ctx=applicationContext;
        this.Datos = Datos;
        this.filtroList = Datos;
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Datos.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return Datos.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return Datos.indexOf(getItem(i));
    }

    public class ViewHolder{
        LikeButton likeButton;
        ImageView smartImageView;
        TextView tvNombre, tvDescripcion, tvDistancia;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, final View view, final ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolder holder;
        ViewGroup viewGroup1 = null;

        if (viewGroup1 == null) {
            viewGroup1 = (ViewGroup) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fila_lista, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();

            holder.smartImageView = (ImageView) viewGroup1.findViewById(R.id.imagenFondoLista);
            holder.tvNombre = (TextView) viewGroup1.findViewById(R.id.nombre_fila_lista);
            holder.tvDescripcion = (TextView) viewGroup1.findViewById(R.id.desc);
            holder.tvDistancia = (TextView) viewGroup1.findViewById(R.id.dist);
            holder.likeButton = (LikeButton) viewGroup1.findViewById(R.id.btnLikeStar);

            final String urlFinal = "http://www.ws.com.mx/images/lista/" + Datos.get(i).getTienda_img_lista();
            Picasso
                    .with(getContext())
                    .load(urlFinal)
                    .transform(new RoundedCornersTransformation(9, 9))
                    .into(holder.smartImageView);

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) holder.likeButton.getLayoutParams();
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_BOTTOM, R.id.imagenFondoLista);
            params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_RIGHT, R.id.imagenFondoLista);
            holder.likeButton.setLayoutParams(params);

            holder.tvNombre.setText(Datos.get(i).getTienda_nombre());
            holder.tvDescripcion.setText(Datos.get(i).getTienda_clasificacion_descripcion());
            holder.tvDistancia.setText(Datos.get(i).getTienda_distancia().toString().substring(0, 4));

            like = Datos.get(i).getFavorito();
            if (like.equals("1")) {
                holder.likeButton.setLiked(true);
            } else {
                holder.likeButton.setLiked(false);
            }

            holder.likeButton.setOnLikeListener(new OnLikeListener() {
                @Override
                public void liked(final LikeButton likeButton) {
                    URL_SET_LIKE = "http://www.ws.com.mx/ws/servicioInsertaFavoritos.php" +
                            "?idCliente=" + userId +
                            "&idTienda=" + Datos.get(i).getTienda_id();
                    DriveLikeBtn(URL_SET_LIKE);
                }

                @Override
                public void unLiked(final LikeButton likeButton) {
                    URL_SET_UNLIKE = "http://www.ws.com.mx/ws/servicioEliminaFavoritos.php" +
                            "?idCliente=" + userId +
                            "&idTienda=" + Datos.get(i).getTienda_id();
                    DriveLikeBtn(URL_SET_UNLIKE);
                }

                private void DriveLikeBtn(final String url_set_like) {
                    class setLike extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
                            String success = null;
                            ServiceHandler jsonParser = new ServiceHandler();
                            String json = jsonParser.makeServiceCall(url_set_like, ServiceHandler.GET);
                            String jsonFinal = "[" + json + "]";
                            Log.e("URL de LIKE: >>>>", url_set_like);
                            if (json != null) {
                                try {
                                    JSONArray likes = new JSONArray(jsonFinal);
                                    JSONObject setLikeObj = (JSONObject) likes.get(0);
                                    likerGS = new LikerClass(
                                            setLikeObj.getInt("success"),
                                            setLikeObj.getString("error_message")
                                    );
                                    success = String.valueOf(likerGS.getSuccess());
                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }
                            return success;
                        }

                        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                            super.onPostExecute(result);
                            retLiker = result;
                        }
                    }
                    new setLike().execute();
                }
            });
            holder.smartImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    //Toast.makeText(getContext(), idTienda.get(i).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    String dataIntent = Datos.get(i).getTienda_id();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), DetailActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("idstore", dataIntent);
                    intent.putExtra("idClient", userId);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            });
            viewGroup1.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder)viewGroup1.getTag();
        }
        imagenAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        return viewGroup1;
    }
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        if (filtro == null){
            filtro = new CustomFilter();
        }
        return filtro;
    }
    class CustomFilter extends Filter{

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            if (constraint != null && constraint.length() > 0){
                constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();
                ArrayList<FilterData> filtro = new ArrayList<FilterData>();
                for (int i = 0; i < filtroList.size(); i++){
                    if (filtroList.get(i).getTienda_nombre().toUpperCase().contains(constraint)){
                        FilterData d = new FilterData(
                                filtroList.get(i).getTienda_id(),
                                filtroList.get(i).getTienda_nombre(),
                                filtroList.get(i).getTienda_img_lista(),
                                filtroList.get(i).getTienda_img_logo(),
                                filtroList.get(i).getTienda_latitud(),
                                filtroList.get(i).getTienda_longitud(),
                                filtroList.get(i).getTienda_distancia(),
                                filtroList.get(i).getTienda_clasificacion_descripcion(),
                                filtroList.get(i).getFavorito());
                        filtro.add(d);
                    }
                }
                results.count = filtro.size();
                results.values = filtro;
            }else{
                results.count = filtroList.size();
                results.values = filtroList;
            }
            return results;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            if (results.count > 0){
                Datos = (ArrayList<FilterData>)results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }else{
                Log.println(Log.INFO, "RESULTS", "FOUND");
                notifyDataSetInvalidated();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ¿Puedes ser un poco más claro? ¿El botón del "Like" se marca solo cuando hay datos o tu lo presionas? Sin entender mucho tu problema puedo decir que quizá se resuelva usando _SharedPreferences_

Comment: Gracias por contestar! mira, te explico con otro ejemplo. En una listview tienes checkbox en los elementos, marcas un checkbox y te desplazas hacia abajo en la lista, y cuando te desplazas nuevamente hacia arriba de la lista, el checkbox aparece desmarcado, ¿cómo puedo hacer para que el checkbox se quede marcado?

Comment: Puedes poner esto dentro de  `getview()`:  `if (convertView == null) {
    holder = new ViewHolder();
    convertView.setTag(holder);
} else {
    holder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
}

holder.likeButton.setChecked(true);` (Bueno esto último funciona si es togglebutton)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo eh logrado utilizando setSelectionFromTop() de la siguiente manera:
Antes de actualizar mi adapter:

```
lastViewedPosition = list.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        View v = list.getChildAt(0);
        topOffset = (v == null)? 0 : v.getTop();
```

Despues, actualizo mi adapter:

```
imagenAdapter = new ImagenAdapter(getContext(), getDatos());
        list.setAdapter(imagenAdapter);
```

Al final, solo utilizo setSelectionFromTop():

```
list.setSelectionFromTop(lastViewedPosition, topOffset);
```

Y me ha funcionado!